# Defining a type inside an Oracle pl/sql function

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create a pl/sql function (my first take at pl/sql functions) that converts base 10 number to base 26 string (my base 26 will be A..Z).

```
create or replace function generateId(numericId IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
declare
  type array_t is varray(26) of CHAR;
  char_array array_t := array_t('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z');
  res varchar2(3);
  targetBase INTEGER := char_array.count;
begin
  LOOP
      res = char_array[REMAINDER(numericId, targetBase)] + result;
      numericId = numericId / targetBase;
  EXIT WHEN (numericId = 0);

  RETURN res;
end;
```

The error I am getting is:

```
Error(2,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "DECLARE" when expecting one of the following:     begin function pragma procedure subtype type <an identifier>    <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> current cursor delete    exists prior external language The symbol "begin" was substituted for "DECLARE" to continue.
```

My guess is I'm sticking declaration into a wrong place but I can't figure out where it should go.

Comment: simple remove `declare`

Comment: that's what i'd suggest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have too many syntax errors in the code.

1. Assignment in oracle is done using := and not =
2. Array indexes are referred using () not []
3. You cannot assign values to IN variables `numericId = numericId / targetBase`
4. Check the syntax for [loop statement](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS402) - you are missing end loop
5. To get array count use COUNT()

   And as the comments suggest
6. Remove Declare

Comment: Yeah, I am working through those right now. It's my first pl/sql function ever :)

Comment: If you are not already using it, try coding in sql developer and its code editor - at least will give syntax/error highlighting.

Comment: I am using it, and was getting errors. I'm all set by the way, the function is working thanks to the answers in this thread

Answer (score 2):

Beside of the syntax  problems here some additional points:

check the input variable before the loop (to avoid endless looping)

use MOD and FLOOR instead of REMAINDER [which is using ROUND](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions152.htm#SQLRF06312)

Here a sample solution (without arrays - that can be easily added)

```
create or replace function generateId(numericId IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
  v_num NUMBER;
  res varchar2(100);
begin
  v_num := numericId;
  if (v_num < 0 OR v_num != trunc(v_num)) then 
     return NULL; /* or raise exeption */
  end if;

  LOOP
     res := chr(ascii('A')  + MOD(v_num, 26)) || res;
     v_num := FLOOR(v_num/26);
  EXIT WHEN (v_num = 0);
  END LOOP;
  RETURN res;
end;
/



select generateId(35286) code from dual;

CODE     
-----
CAFE
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove *declared*.

According to the syntax rules (for example [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions.php)) it does not belong there.

Answer (score 0):

No need to write to declare after CREATE OR REPLACE. Your declare section has already started from create keyword.
Again there should be end loop if you don't want to put it in infinite loop.